# Usage of power supply with different output than input of consuming device

Tags: power-supply, output, input

I'm about to use a power supply with output of 29V 1.8A for a device (linear actuator) with an input of 12V 5A. Is this a good plan regarding functionality and safety? I'm not even sure if this is a valid question.

Comment: Welcome! Your linear actuator will probably burn up or your power supply will trip on overcurrent. Get yourself a 12 V 5+ A power supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not safe or functional for your device. If you connect the power supply directly to the device, you will apply a voltage beyond its designed voltage and may destroy its onboard electronics.

Normally, you would be able to use something like a switching regulator to convert 29 V to 12 V. However, such regulators cannot produce more power than you put into them, so they won't work here; your 1.8 A at 29V supply can deliver approximately 52 watts to the regulator, but the regulator needs just over 60 watts to deliver 60 W (12 V * 5 A) to the load.